# How to use Rolllup summary field when there are two child objects with one master

Tags: roll-up-summary

Custom object Plan is master on two objects, Class and Plan Product.

Both class and plan product has estimated value as fields.

I want something like...*Plan(master's estimated value)=Class's estimated value+ planproduct's estimated value.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to create 2 separate rollups then use a formula to add them together to get your total.
Rollup 1: `Class_Estimated_Value__c`
Rollup 2: `Product_Estimated_Value__c`
Formula: `Plan_Estimated_Value__c = Class_Estimated_Value__c + Product_Estimated_Value__`c

Comment: Thanks Jenny,Could you also let me know the Formula field behavior in Trigger.As in existing functionality  Plan_Estimated_Value__c is roll up. But when i change it to formula field(to satisfy new requirement of class),will existing triggers behavior would have any impact.

Comment: @ArunSharma if the trigger sets the field then you would have an issue. You can either adjust the trigger to accomplish your task, create a separate field for the summing of the 2 separate rollups or if the trigger is no longer needed remove the trigger then change your field.

Comment: No Trigger don,t set the field it just use this field in query to get the values(actually trigger further roll up it to opportunity total premium),i was wondering how would formula field behave in before and after trigger.Like for example if trigger tries to do soql on Plan_Estimated_Value__c,would that be available as (Class_Estimated_Value__c + Product_Estimated_Value__c) or formula fields calculate by salesforce after triggers over.

Comment: @ArunSharma I'm not sure off the top of my head, can you run a couple tests and see?